# Struts2 internalization

Tags: java, internationalization, struts2

I'm try to internalize my application with the next code:

For the jsp I have this:

```xml
  <table>
    <tr class="trlleno">
      <td>
        <div id="Panel_cliente">
          <s:select label="Selecciona un idioma" name="IdiomaID" id="IdiomaID" 
          headerValue="--Selecciona un idioma--" headerKey="-1" 
          list="#{'1':'Español','2':'English','3':'Deutch','4':'Português','5':'русский','6':'Français'}" value="2"/> 
        </div> 
      </td>
    </tr>

    <td class="trboton" colspan="2" align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="CAMBIAR IDIOMA" class="divboton"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table> 
</form>
```

In the action I have this:

```java
public class CambiarIdiomaAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware{

private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
Map session;

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();

    int idm=Integer.valueOf(servletRequest.getParameter("IdiomaID"));
     System.out.println(idm);
     //Trying with English
     Locale locale=new Locale("en","EN");
    return "SUCCESS";
}


@Override
public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.servletRequest = request;
}

public HttpServletRequest getServletRequest() {
    return servletRequest;
}
}
```

When I see if there is a change with the language, I see nothing, no changes. Why?. Thanks so much

Comment: Is that all the code you are using? I can't see where are you using the locale object you are instantiating.

Comment: That's not even valid HTML; when posting snippets it's quite useful to post working code.

Comment: Deutsch, not Deutch. If you really need to have to do this mistake and implement language switcher, at least please avoid such typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set locale in session if you want to change locale.

If you put this code in an Action:

```
ActionContext context = ActionContext.getContext();
context.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

You will change the locale of your app to English.

In your code you are doing nothing, you only are setting a variable `locale` put you don't do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to change locale in your action then use

```
ActionContext.getContext().setLocale(locale)
```

and to put it in HTTP session

```
session.put(I18nInterceptor.DEFAULT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, locale)
```

But Struts2 has out of the box localization support. I suggest you to read about localization in Struts2 http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/localization.html.